# Replace for loop with linq using any

Tags: javascript, typescript, linq, lambda, any

I have the following code in typescript:

```
public executeTest(test: Test): void {
    const testFilters: Record<string> = getTestFilters();
    let isTestingRequired: boolean = false;
    
    for (let i: number = 0; i < testFilters.length; i++) {
        if(test.Name === testFilters[i].Name){
            isTestingRequired = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to replace the above for loop using LINQ as below, however I am getting errors.

```
let isTestingRequired: boolean = testFilters.any((filter.): boolean => {
    return filter.Name  === test.Name 
});
```

Comment: `testFilters.some(filter => filter.Name === test.Name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make your `array` enumerable first using `Enumerable.from()` like this:

```js
var array = [{name: "John"}, {name: "Test"}];

var result = Enumerable.from(array)
  .any(obj => obj.name == "Test");

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/3.2.4/linq.min.js"></script>
```